# Rails using build with checkbox with has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-one

I have user that has_one profile but not all users need a profile. I'm looking for a way to create the profile only when a checkbox is checked on the user form (either via update or create).

My models look like this -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :profile
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base    
belongs_to :user
```

Ideally in my user form, I'd like to include a checkbox, when checked this would create the profile and set user_id in profile to the corresponding user ID.

I know that in my Users Controller, doing

```
@user.build_profile
```

Will create the profile on update but again, not all users need a profile created.

Answer (score 0):

Make a checkbox in your form, but without using form_for symbol 'f'.Instead use check_box_tag

```
check_box_tag :create_profile
```

now in your create /update function create profile if this box is checked

```
@user.build_profile  if params[:create_profile]
```

Comment: If visiting edit user page, the above does not seem to pre-check the box if user has an existing association with a profile, which is surely the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying something similar (using Rails 4.2.4) and arrived at this solution.

**app/models/user.rb**

The `allow_destroy: true` will allow you to destroy the profile association through a user form (more [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for-label-One-to-one)).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :profile
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, allow_destroy: true
```

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

You'll need to build the user's associated profile instance (in the `new` and `edit` methods) for this to work correctly in the respective forms.

When editing a user it is possible that a profile association already exists. The `edit` method will use the associated profile if it does exists (setting the form with its values) or create a new profile instance if not.

Notice also that the `user_params` include `profile_attributes: [:_destroy, :id]` which will be the values sent by the checkbox.

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_profile
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def edit
  @user.profile || @user.build_profile
end

def update
  if @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, profile_attributes: [:_destroy, :id])
  end
```

**app/views/users/new.html.rb** and **app/views/users/edit.html.rb**

Use the `fields_for` method in the form to submit data for the association (more on nested attributes, specifically one-to-one relationships, [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)).

Use the checkbox `destroy` attribute to create/destroy the associated profile. The value of the `checked` attribute within the curly braces sets the default state of the checkbox depending on whether or not the association exists (more under the 'More complicated relationships' header [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/)).  The `'0'` and `'1'` that follow invert the `destroy` method (i.e. create the association if checkbox is checked and delete it if not) (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363154/rails-3-checkbox-for-create-opposite-of-destroy)).

```
<%= form_for @user do |user| %>

  <%= user.fields_for :profile do |profile| %>
    <div class='form-item'>
      <%= profile.check_box :_destroy, { checked: profile.object.persisted? }, '0', '1' %>
      <%= profile.label :_destroy, 'Profile', class: 'checkbox' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= user.submit 'Submit', class: 'button' %>

<% end %>
```

You can probably also delete the primary key `id` from the profile model given it is unnecessary in this scenario and this [link](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/) is very useful in that regard.